# Mixture Distribution of Normals

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $f_1(x), \dots, f_n(x)$ be probability density functions of normal distribution.

$w_1, \dots, w_n$ be the weight and we have $\sum_i w_i=1$ and $w_i\geq0 $.

Hence $g(x) = \sum_i w_i f_i(x)$ is the mixture distribution of normals.

What is the probability density function for $h(x)=\frac{ w_if_i(x)}{g(x)}$? Do we have a name for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Posterior distribution for $i$ given $x$?

Comment: Are the random variables independent?

Comment: Hi, I just copy the definition from the Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you ask "What is the probability distribution for [something]?" then normally I'd expect "something" to be a random variable. I don't see that here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I try to do is to simplify it and see whether or not it follows a "well-known" (e.g. normal, beta, etc) probability distribution. If this is the case, then it might have some nice properties.